# Saxon genitive for company products

Tags: saxon-genitive

Is it correct to use the Saxon genitive when talking about the products of a given company? For example:

> Apple's iPhone / Apple iPhone?

Of course, I have no doubt with products whose denomination includes the name of the company, such as Apple Watch. In such a case, the question, yet awkward, would be:

> Apple's Apple Watch / Apple Apple Watch?

Thank you.

EDIT: Another example would be:

> Microsoft's Word / Microsoft Word

I have seen both ways.